# Same function not working on different properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function to filter a list in an array. The function works when filtering the 'brands' property, but I can not get it to work to filter the 'material' property.

It is exactly the same and does the exact same thing except for the fact that it filters a different property. I have no idea what could be stopping this, but:

1. 'brands' function WILL run when both are present, and standalone
2. 'material' function WILL NOT run when either both are present or standing alone.

**HTML (brands function check boxes)[working]**

```
<div class="filter-content">    
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeBrand('Brand A')"/>Brand A<br>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeBrand('Brand B')"/>Brand B<br>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeBrand('Brand C')"/>Brand C<br>
</div>
```

**JS (brands function)[working]**

```
$scope.brandIncludes = [];

    $scope.includeBrand = function(brand) {
        var i = $.inArray(brand, $scope.brandIncludes);
        if (i > -1) {
            $scope.brandIncludes.splice(i, 1);
        } else {
            $scope.brandIncludes.push(brand);
        }
    }

    $scope.brandFilter = function(products) {
        if ($scope.brandIncludes.length > 0) {
            if ($.inArray(products.brand, $scope.brandIncludes) < 0)
                return;
        }

        return products;
    }
}
```

**HTML (material function check boxes)[not working]**

```
    <div class="filter-content">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeMaterial('dry')"/>Dry Materials<br>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeMaterial('wet')"/>Wet Materials<br>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeMaterial('oil')"/>Oils<br>
</div>
```

**JS (material function)[not working]**

```
$scope.materialIncludes = [];

    $scope.includeMaterial = function(material) {
        var i = $.inArray(material, $scope.materialIncludes);
        if (i > -1) {
            $scope.materialIncludes.splice(i, 1);
        } else {
            $scope.materialIncludes.push(material);
        }
    }

    $scope.materialFilter = function(products) {
        if ($scope.materialIncludes.length > 0) {
            if ($.inArray(products.material, $scope.materialIncludes) < 0)
                return;
        }

        return products;
    }
}
```

I am still a novice to angular, can I not run the same function? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've spent probably 10 hours over the past two days staring at my JS to find an answer. I seemed to have forgotten there is a "filter function" that gets called in order to solve my problem. I pin pointed that the fact of the matter wasn't that my filter wasn't working, but more or less, wasn't being included in my HTML.

Here is what I had to change to get it working:

```
<div class="product-results">
            <div class="info" ng-repeat="p in products | filter:brandFilter | filter:materialFilter">
                {{p.name}}
                {{p.brand}}
              <img 
         ng-if="products.src"
         ng-src="{{products.src}}">
            </div>
```

I had to add "| filter:materialFilter" in my class that was printing the array to screen.